# iOS 7.1 Nested UICollectionView in a UIPopover

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview, uipopover

I am working with a small team of developers on an iOS project for iPads. The project calls for a UIPopover with a UICollectionView nested inside. The collection will ultimately be icons. So in the end, it would be a popover containing a grid of dynamically chosen icons. Unfortunately, the tutorials I have seen for UICollectionViews are mostly single view applications or are using storyboards (my group is using .xib files). I am able to get the popover to show up, but I am not quite sure how to go about setting up the UICollectionView and custom cells for the grid. I have tried creating the collection view inside of the popover method, but that did not work well. I am currently trying to create a custom UICollectionViewController subclass. The popover displays the UICollectionView, but not the custom cells.

This is my popover method:

```
- (IBAction)displayPopover{
    WMGAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    //image array is the array which will hold the dynamically chosen icons
    [self populateImageArray];    
    // Configure layout
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(130, 130)];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    // create collectionview
    WMGCollectionViewController *gridController = [[WMGCollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    [gridController.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CVCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];    
    //if popover is already visible
    if ([self.selectorController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self.selectorController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    //popover not visible
    else {

        self.selectorController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:gridController];
        self.selectorController.delegate = self;
        [self.selectorController presentPopoverFromRect:_firstImage.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft | UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
        self.selectorController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(450, 500);
    }
}
```

My custom UICollectionViewController class files look like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WMGCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UICollectionView *grid;

@end
```

and

```
#import "WMGCollectionViewController.h"
#import "CVCell.h"

@interface WMGCollectionViewController ()

@end

@implementation WMGCollectionViewController

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return 32;
}

- (CVCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    // we're going to use a custom UICollectionViewCell, which will hold an image and its label
    //
    // Setup cell identifier
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";
    CVCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // make the cell's title the actual NSIndexPath value
    cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%ld,%ld}", (long)indexPath.row, (long)indexPath.section];

    return cell;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.25f alpha:1.0f];
    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

As far as I can tell, I have all of the outlets set up fine. Am I doing something glaringly wrong? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of the UIViewController, "controller". Why not make WMGCollectionViewController the content controller of the popover? Also, you have the line, WMGCollectionViewController *gridController = [WMGCollectionViewController alloc]. You should NEVER have an alloc without an init. You also shouldn't need an IBOutlet for the collection view, a UICollectionViewController already has a collectionView property (so you shouldn't be alloc init'ing a collection view in initWithNibName either).

Comment: @rdelmar the UIViewController was left over from a previous implementation using a scroll view. Thank you for the tips. I am still fairly new to Objective C. Would any of these issues cause the UICollectionView to not show up?

Comment: @rdelmar When I try to make the WMGCollectionViewController be the content controller, the app crashes at the `initWithContentViewController` line.

Comment: Did you fix the line that only has the alloc with no init first? Do you get any error with that crash? And yes, some of those issues could cause the collection view to not show up.

Comment: @rdelmar I did fix the alloc with no init first. I got the collection view to show after working through a couple of crashes. I cannot get the cells to show yet.

Comment: I see you have a custom cell. Where did you make it? Do you have it and the collectionViewController in a storyboard?

Comment: @rdelmar I made a .xib for the custom cell. I did some maneuvering and it finally showed the cells. I am going to edit the question and post the final code I got to get the whole thing working. Thanks a bunch for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was not registering the Nib for the custom cell I had created.

```
WMGCollectionViewController *gridController = [[WMGCollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
[gridController.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CVCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];
```

Once I changed the `registerClass...` to `registerNib...` (as shown in the edited question), the cells showed up.